# When do UIAppearance proxy rules get applied to new view controller?

Tags: ios, uiappearance

I'm wandering when exactly do UIAppearance rules get applied to some new view controller?

I've made some global rules and I call them in my app delegate. That way all UIButtons look that same. But now I want to modify just appearance of one UIButton. I've tried putting the code to remove it's background inside `- (void)viewDidLoad` but it's not working - UIAppearance rules aren't applied yet. In one ViewController I put modification code inside `- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews` and it worked perfectly, but now in another ViewController it doesn't work (code is the same).

Where is it safe to override UIAppearance rules?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

According to the 2011 WWDC video introducing UIAppearance, the customizations are applied right before `-layoutSubviews` is called on the view.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to customise one specific button you should either:

1. Alter the properties of the button instance directly, and not touch the appearance settings for the class, or
2. Use the `appearanceWhenContainedIn:` method like below:

   ```
   [[UIButton appearanceWhenContainedIn:[CustomView class], nil]
    setBackgroundImage:myButtonImage
               forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   ```

That way you can still use the appearance proxy for your specific button (when you know it's contained in a specific view), and not alter the general appearance settings.